# Get element attributes

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have an HTML file. I need to get the element attributes and but it's not happening as I am getting `var elementType = target.getAttribute('data-type');`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

I just don't know how I can get the element attribute. Please help.

```js
var setAllEvents = $("[my-noteEvent]");
for (var i = 0; i < setAllEvents.length; i++) {
    //call function to work with
    this.bindingAllEvents(setAllEvents[i]);
}

bindingAllEvents: function(setElements) {

    var element = document.getElementById(setElements.getAttribute('data-element')); // Get Element the event is set on
    var target = document.getElementById(setElements.getAttribute('data-target')); // Get Element that is the target of the event
    var event = setElements.getAttribute('data-event'); // What type of event to run
    var action = setElements.getAttribute('data-action'); // Action to take on event
    var elementType = target.getAttribute('data-type');
  
    if (elementType === 'dropdown-label') {
        target = target.parentelement;
    }

    element.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //do something here when all is good
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="form--input form--input-container form--select hasPlaceholder" data-type="dropdown-label" data-required="true">
    <label for="countries">Dropdown</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="countries" name="maritalStatus">
    <input class="input--main" type="button" data-element="select" value="">
    <span class="placeholder">A Dropdown with stuff</span>
    <span class="selectChoice"></span>
    <div class="framework dropdown dropdown--select-container">
        <div id="" class="framework dropdown--select-item" data-value="UK" data-option="0">
            <p class="framework text--paragraph     ">
                UK
            </p>
            <span class="dropdown--item-line"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="framework dropdown--select-item" data-value="Russia" data-option="1">
            <p class="atom text--paragraph     ">
                Russia
            </p>
            <span class="dropdown--item-line"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div my-noteEvent="" data-element="maritalStatus" data-target="myTarget" data-event="onchange" data-action="[{'Single':{'show':'#div1 #div3'}, {'married':{'show':'#div1 #div3'}}]">
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't tag jQuery if you're asking about plain JS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It seems the first line of the js snippet is jQuery.

Comment: @undefined Very true. That just makes the rest of the code even more confusing. OP, if you're looking for a jQuery solution please feel free to add the jQuery tag back in. For now I'll leave it off as the issue within the question appears to be irrelevant of jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can I solve this?

Comment: The issue is because `target` is `undefined`. You need to determine why that is. I'd start by checking the value of `setElements.getAttribute('data-targets')` and make sure it's a valid `id` in your page

Answer (score 1):

I quote

> ```
> <div my-noteEvent="" data-element="#maritalStatus" data-target="myTarget" data-event="onchange"
>  data-action="[{'Single':{'show':'#div1 #div3'},
>  {'married':{'show':'#div1 #div3'}}]">
> ```

In your html, your attributes are named data-element="#maritalStatus" data-target="myTarget" respectively, yet you add an s at both in your code:

> var element =
>   document.getElementById(setElements.getAttribute('data-elements')); //
>   Get Element the event is set on
>       var target = document.getElementById(setElements.getAttribute('data-targets'));

remove the s at the end.

Furthermore if you are going to fetch by id using document.getElementById(variable), variable shouldn't start with a pound sign.

remove # in #maritalStatus

You are getting an error because target is null since you can't find it.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for me to see in action?

Comment: I've edited the piece you told to edit, still firing an error

Comment: there is no element with the id myTarget in your snippet.